# Gradle error in Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, gradle

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1
Error:(44, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4
```

build.gradle(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pritish.sawant.com.simplypubliccloud"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    // FirebaseUI


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am using `Firebase`,Facebook libraries.I am getting the following errors.I tried everything.Please help me if you know how to resolve this error.I am also receiving the following error 
Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.1
I tried clicking on Install Repository and sync project,but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.1
>
> Error:(41, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:26.0.1

You should change your **`buildToolsVersion`** version .

**Don't**

```
 buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

**Do**

```
 buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`** .

Comment: Doesn't work.I cleaned my project as well as my gradle and synced it.I am getting the same error

Comment: @LataSawant use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1`

Comment: I added compile 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1' in my app's gradle. Still it gives me same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more *Dependency* to your list.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
```

Then *clean* and *rebuild* your project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to change the repositories just as the demo instruction--->

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenLocal()
    google()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
 }
```